# D3 scaleTime truncating first date

Tags: d3.js

Attempting an x axis time scale in D3 but losing the first date. The axis displays fine but without Wed, May 18 the first date. Am I inadvertently binding the first object to a parent element? Inspection shows there isn't a hidden 'g' with the missing date. Thanks for any ideas.

```
let svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
  
    let xScale = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { 
        console.log(d.dateob);
        return d.dateob; 
    }))
    .range([0, width]); 
    let x_axis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
    
svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(x_axis)
```

console.log(d.dateob)

```
Wed May 18 2022 17:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Thu May 19 2022 14:12:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Fri May 20 2022 07:22:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Sun May 22 2022 03:06:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Sun May 22 2022 23:06:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Mon May 23 2022 17:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Tue May 24 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Tue May 24 2022 07:24:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Wed May 25 2022 21:53:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Thu May 26 2022 22:58:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Fri May 27 2022 16:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Fri May 27 2022 16:04:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Fri May 27 2022 16:06:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Fri May 27 2022 16:58:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Sat May 28 2022 10:23:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Comment: what is more likely is that some dates are not shown because there's a limit on how many ticks can be shown 

(example : if you have 10 ticks and 20 dates , it will show only 10 dates but take in consideration all 20 when making the Axis)

Comment: Do you store your dates as strings ? What is `data` ?

Comment: Dates are Date objects.